# Is mapping a part of Data or Logic/Business layer?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, architecture, n-tier-architecture

I'm working on N-tier service application, which is basically *(I have very specific question, but I need to first explain the whole situation/architecture)*:

**Data --> Logic (Business) --> WCF Service --> Host (Winddows Service)**, where:

**Data**, is the data persistence but it has no connection strings. Everything is taken from another WCF service. So all I have here is `ServiceReferences` and one class `FooData`, with a few methods (it implements `IFooData` interface). As you can see below it returns `Bar` object, which is from `BarServiceReference` auto-generated by VS.

```
using FooService.Data.BarServiceReference;

public class FooData : IFooData
{
    public BarDto Func1(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (BarServiceClient client = new BarServiceClient())
            {
                return client.GetBar(id);
            }
        }
        catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Inner exception in BarServiceClient: { ex.Message }", ex);
        }
    }        
}
```

**Logic**, here I have `IMapper`'s mapping profiles and the class `FooLogic` where I inject via DI `IFooData` and `IMapper`. Inside that class I have a few methods. One of them:

```
public class FooLogic
{
    private IMapper Mapper { get; }
    private IFooData FooData { get; }
    public FooLogic(IMapper mapper, IFooData fooData)
    {
        Mapper = mapper;
        FooData = fooData;
    }

    public Bar GetBar(int id)
    {
        BarDto barDto = FooData.Func1(itemId);
        Bar bar = Mapper.Map<BarDto, Bar>(barDto);  

        // There are lot more, taken from the Data layer.
        // Some operations are performed.  The Bar is basically modified a little bit/adjusted



        return bar;
    }
}
```

As you can see my logic layer must know about the "BarDto", which force me to include the Reference using. I'm not sure about that.

**The Question...**

Should I return `Bar` from the `Data` Layer instead of `BarDto`? In that case I will have to inject IMapper into Data layer. I've read a lot and some people do it in Data layer, some in Logic layer. Quotes like *Your mapping should be in Logic layer not in Data layer*, so I'm confused.

Thanks for help

Comment: Data layer should depend on logic layer by implementing data access interfaces. By having mapping in business layer you will leak implementation details of data layer to business layer, which will break main purpose of layering.

Comment: @Fabio thanks, just to make sure, you're saying that the mapping should be done on the Data side (incoming data to logic entities), correct? I was writing unit tests and I caught myself referencing Data layer while writing IFooData mock. So (correct me if I'm wrong), `IFooData` interface should return Logic entities, right?

Comment: Yes, business layer will create data access interfaces with business entities. Data access layer will implement those interfaces, so if data access layer use own entity types it will be responsible for mapping them back to business types

Comment: @Fabio So where should I put `IFooData` interface? If I'll leave it in `Data` project then `Logic` will have to reference `Data` project. Is that correct?

Comment: `IFooData` interface should be in the business/logic layer. But it's implementation will be in the data layer

Comment: @Fabio thanks. Should the transition from Logic to WCF Service be done the same way? So `IFooLogic` in WCF Service project? Should the `FooLogic` returns Dtos that WCF Service will return? My WCF Service are basically a Logic proxy, no logic there.

Comment: @Fabio is 100% correct. Your project should have a service layer which returns request / response messages which include DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll call your another WCF service as *data source service* which has its own data contracts that it returns through its operations, to your data access layer. Now your service layer should not know anything about your data source service objects. It should be agnostic of them, so in future, if you plan to use another data source instead of another WCF service, you don't have to worry about recompiling your service layer. Your service layer should not have any reference to data sources, which is one of the idea behind using separate data access layer.

So to answer your question, do the mapping in the data layer it self and not in the service layer.

Comment: *Your service layer should not have any reference to data sources* - how come will `Logic` project know about which Data functions to call? Where should `IFooData` be implemented? Should I create separate `Core` project with interfaces only?

Comment: Yes, a separate project for all common interfaces and classes. `IFooData` should be implemented in the Data project. The Logic project only contains the reference to Common project and load the implementations at run time using dependency injection. You can register all dependencies in the main project using any DI container.